# is the undefined reference to vtable error solved by modern g++ compilers?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, virtual-functions

according to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#vtables/) virtual functions must be defined otherwise linker complains & reports error *"undefined reference to vtable"*, but why doesn't [ideone](http://ideone.com/ptPoMf/) compiler give any errors for the following code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Test
{
    public:
    Test()
    {
        cout<<"test() is called\n";
    }
    virtual void test();
};
int main() {
    Test t;
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You aren't calling the undefined member anywhere.

Comment: @juanchopanza I have seen on some compilers that undefined virtual functions results in errors even if the member is not called. I can't remember if that's allowed by the standard or not.

Comment: Related, refers to C++03 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642124/should-a-virtual-function-essentially-have-a-definition

Comment: Probably because (after inlining and other optimisations) the program never tries to use the *vtable*, so there aren't any references that need defining. You'd probably still get an error if you did anything that needed it.

Comment: @NeilKirk That's plausible. But I am pretty sure calling `Test::test()` would have triggered an error.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Not necessarily. In a simple example like this, the dynamic type is known at compile time, so it's likely to be called non-virtually.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: And, when it is, the call will fail because no definition is available.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Sorry, I wasn't thinking straight. Of course you'll get an error; but perhaps not the one about a missing vtable (which is what the question is about).

Comment: C++ is case-sensitive, so the constructor `Test::Test()` is different from the virtual function `void Test::test()`. And it only produces an error (in the linking step) when an undefined function is called.

Comment: @tmlen: Not necessarily. It can also produce the error the question is asking about if a virtual function is undefined, even if no virtual function is called. A less trivial example, which can't optimise out the object creation, would need to initialise the object's *vtable*, and would fail if that didn't exist. This particular compiler produces the *vtable* in the same translation unit as the first non-pure, non-virtual function (if there is such a thing), and will fail to produce it if that function isn't defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't read the documentation properly. The first sentence in the relevant paragraph says:

> The ISO C++ Standard specifies that all virtual methods of a class that are not pure-virtual must be defined, but does not require any diagnostic for violations of this rule [class.virtual]/8.

So, it is expected that you may not get an error, especially since you are not actually invoking `test()` (despite the lie in the constructor's output).

Speaking practically, you are likely to get this diagnostic only under the following circumstances:

- you call a virtual function that you did not define
- you instantiate an object whose `virtual` destructor you did not define

But make no mistake: your program has undefined behaviour regardless.

Comment: *despite the lie in the constructor's output* hahahahaha